# Unity Services Analytics Will Not be Initialized

Tags: unity-game-engine, analytics, game-development

When I try and send an event to unity analytics (services, not legacy) I am getting the following error:

servicesInitializationException: The Analytics service has not been initialized. Please initialize Unity Services.

The initialize script I am using is:

```cs
using System;
using Unity.Services.Core;
using Unity.Services.Core.Environments;
using UnityEngine;

public class InitializeUnityServices : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string environment = "production";

    async void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            var options = new InitializationOptions()
                .SetEnvironmentName(environment);

            await UnityServices.InitializeAsync(options);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // An error occurred during services initialization.
        }
    }
}
```

The event script that is not working is:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Unity.Services.Analytics;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Analytics;


public class analyticsEvent_ScenePlayed_MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                                   {
                                       { "Scene Played", "Main Menu"},
                                   };
         AnalyticsService.Instance.CustomData("ScenePlayed_MainMenu", parameters);
//            Analytics.CustomEvent("ScenePlayed_MainMenu");
         Debug.Log("Sent ScenePlayed_MainMenu analytics event");
         AnalyticsService.Instance.Flush();
         Debug.Log("Flushed ScenePlayed_MainMenu analytics event");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Both these scripts are attached to a component in a scene. is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Did you set up your project in the Unity developer's dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have the 'Automatically initialize Unity Gaming Services' checkbox on the IAP Catalog Window

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.purchasing@4.8/manual/UnityIAPInitializeUnityGamingServices.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain but it could be because both script logic are booted with `Start` and since the order of execution isn't guaranteed (unless you specified a script execution order) the initialization happens after you send your event.

Other possibility, since the `InitializeUnityServices` runs with `async void Start()` it means the task isn't awaited for completion before moving so the initialization could be happening at the same time you send your event.